# What we should do when we have a guess but cannot comment a question?

Tags: support

What I should do when I have a good guess, but I am not sure if I am right. So, I would like only to comment, but I do not have reputation for that.
What is the approach in these cases?

Comment: Wait until you have more reputation. It only takes 50. Shouldn't take long to accrue.

Comment: I had to wait for an year or two just for getting started with SFSE, initially was blocked because rules of the platform were unknown to me (was already contributing to Salesforce developer forum). So, have patience until you reach 50, its worth it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll just convert this into an answer:

> Wait until you have more reputation. It only takes 50. Shouldn't take long to accrue.

You need 33 more reputation to be able to comment anywhere you please. If you want to contribute enough to make comments, surely you can attain that privilege!